# steps to follow in socket programming for a multiplayer online game in actionscript-3 flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, socketserver

I have created a multiplayer ludo game using actionscript-3 flash, I want to uploaded into website, before this I want to use socket server to this game.I have no idea on socket programming. how to start socket programming to this project? please suggest me any links or ideas which I can follow step by step.

Answer (score 0):

1. a socket is simply a way of activating a specific service on a specific port.
2. to enable online gaming you have to open a port on both the application and have to create a stream between both hosts.
3. after that you can play on multiple terminals on the same time.